# Change the orientation of chart at runtime

Tags: android, achartengine

I have an issue which like to overcome. I'm using the achartengine to draw a bar chart on android application. At the first time, i can set the orientation for the chart by using "rederer.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL)" and it works fine. But what i'd like it when we rotate the device, the chart will change it's orientation, so the bar in chart will change respectively like this:

1. When the device is in state "landscape" the chart will change to "horizontal"
2. When the device is in state "portrait" the chart will change to "vertical"

Could anyone tell me how to do that? Thanks for any comments.

Thanks

Clark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should override your `onConfigurationChange(newConfig)` method in your `Activity` and when detecting a change, just change the bar chart orientation in the way you mentioned. You may need to call `repaint()` on your chart view.

Read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html) for more information on handling orientation changes.

Comment: Hi Dan. I can detect the change of device, what i'd like to overcome is function in the achartengine to let me can change the orientation of chart at runtime. Could you tell me more about the way to change orientation of chart?

Comment: Just call renderer.setOrientation() and then chartView.repaint();

Comment: Hi Dan, i got a problem when rotate the device, like above, when i put the device in LANSCAPE, the bar will view like this:

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3NUAgD0tB0YLVpPV2pab05GZDA/edit

But when POTRAIT, the bar show like this:

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3NUAgD0tB0YRG5tX1c3MElXZTg/edit

I don't know where to fix the problem with that grid, because when i rotate the device, i just need to intiate the chart with new orientation. Could you help me to solve the grid problem?